# Allowing illegal requests to webserver

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am making a akka webserver, and running into an issue.  When receiving a request that contains a `%` character, I get the following error: `Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Illegal request-target: Invalid input '%', expected HEXDIG (line 1, column 12): /path?val=%%test%%`.  While I understand that `%%` is a bad encoding, I would like to log and process the request, since I do receive them. Is there anyway to stop the auto 400 response, and receive the data as received?  Here is a minimal working example of my program:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpMethods._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ ContentTypes, HttpEntity }
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import scala.io.StdIn
import akka.http.scaladsl.server._
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpMethods._
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import Directives._

object Main extends App {

  implicit def myRejectionHandler =
    RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
      .handle {
        case _: IllegalUriException =>
          println("Illegal URI rejection")
          complete(HttpResponse(200))
      }
      .handleAll[MethodRejection] { methodRejections =>
        println("Handle all")
        complete(HttpResponse(200))
      }
      .result()

  implicit def myExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler =
    ExceptionHandler {
        case _: IllegalUriException =>
          println ("Illegal URI Exception")
          complete(HttpResponse(200))
    }


  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val route = {
    handleExceptions(myExceptionHandler) {
      get {
        path("path") {
          complete("path!")
        }
      }
    }
  }

  val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt("0.0.0.0", 80).bind(route)
  println(s"Server online at http://localhost:80/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine()
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind())
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
}
```

I also did attempt to set

```
akka.http {
   parsing {
      uri-parsing-mode = relaxed
   }
}
```

But did not solve this issue

Comment: Did you try `akka.http.server.parsing = relaxed`?

Comment: Sorry, what field in `akka.http.server.parsing`? I only see two fields in there `max-content-length` and `error-handler`, neither seem like it would accept `relaxed` as a value.

Comment: I just tried setting `akka.http.server.parsing.uri-parsing-mode = relaxed` and `akka.http.client.uri-parsing-mode = relaxed` and still get the same error.  If it matters I am using `akka-http 10.2.1`

Comment: JFYI relax mode prohibits '%' char in URI - https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.2.1/akka-http-core/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/UriSpec.scala#L425-L432

Comment: @Eumcoz typically '%' char must be encoded as '%25' in URI cause otherwise it treated as beginning of encoded special character - $# etc. You can only add global exception handler to log such request https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html

Comment: Thanks for the information, It does not seem to me that the exception handler works for this error, I'm looking into more places where I can catch the error, but have not found anything yet.

Comment: @Eumcoz akka may treat `IllegalUriException` as a rejection. Have you tried to use own rejection handler?

Comment: That did not work either, updated my original post with my current minimal setup with rejection and exception handling incase I am doing something wrong(very new to akka).